# Cannot find dependent libraries for openni2.jni - OpenNI 2, Java, Kinect For Windows

Tags: java, kinect, openni

I'm trying to get started with OpenNI 2 using Java and the Kinect for Windows Sensor (Not the Xbox version) yet am experiencing significant problems.

While the sample SimpleViewer program functions correctly, I cannot get the Java equivalent to run (SimpleViewer.java). It successfully compiles after I added org.openni.jar to my classpath, yet upon attempting to run the program I am faced with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Open
NI2\Tools\OpenNI2.jni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.openni.NativeMethods.<clinit>(NativeMethods.java:44)
    at org.openni.OpenNI.initialize(OpenNI.java:113)
    at OpenNITest.SimpleViewerApplication.main(SimpleViewerApplication.java:
```

190)

After reading up on similar problems I attempted the following to try to resolve the problem, having thrown pretty much every library I could find in OpenNI into the Tools folder (Contents of Lib and Tools/OpenNI2/Drivers) in case it wasn't finding the correct dependencies.

```
java -Djava.library.path="C:/Program Files/OpenNI2/Tools" OpenNITest.SimpleViewerApplication
```

I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, Java 1.7.0_21 and the latest version of OpenNI 2. OpenNITest is the name of the folder and package I put the sample application in.

If anyone has any advice for trying to resolve this problem it would be greatly appreciated as I've been at it for 3 hours yet am still failing miserably at resolving it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Finally got this working, add the following and load the library OpenNI2.dll (directory to wherever it is on your machine or use loadLibrary() if you want a relative path) and all will be merry, just wish OpenNI had included an actually working Java sample!

```
static {
    try {
        System.load("C:\\Program Files\\OpenNI2\\Tools\\OpenNI2.dll");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Also the -D option on java can now be removed.